# Improve Select perfomance and readability

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, readability

I use the oracle sql developer.
I have one doubt and one thing that i'm having a little trouble with:
1)I need to do a select that have some rules.

- This select must return the information from table1.
- Table2 is a "child" from table1.
- The date from each table must be from the same month/year of the current one.
- The idrule must not be no in both tables.
- In the final return it must have only the data that from table1 must only be the ones that the nrtable and the nrgroupby are in the sub-select that i've said.

If was not clear i've made one, that works, but it's kind of silly, because i think there is some way of doing this that or is more efficient or more readable, because this way i had to rewrit almost the same select two times:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE NRSEQTABLE1 IN
      (SELECT DECODE(T1.NRSEQTABLE1,NULL, T2.NRSEQTABLE1, T1.NRSEQTABLE1) AS NRSEQTABLE1
      FROM
        (SELECT NRSEQTABLE1,
          NRNUM2
        FROM TABLE1 T1
        WHERE TO_CHAR(DTHRTABLE1, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
        AND IDRULE                      = 'NO'
        ) T1
      FULL JOIN
        (SELECT NRSEQTABLE1,
          NRNUM2
        FROM TABLE2 T2
        WHERE TO_CHAR(DTHRTABLE2, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
        AND IDRULE                       = 'NO'
        ) T2
      ON T2.NRSEQTABLE1 = T1.NRSEQTABLE1
      AND T2.NRNUM2       = T1.NRNUM2
      )
    AND NRGROUPBY IN
      (SELECT NRGROUPBY
      FROM TABLE1
      WHERE NRSEQTABLE1 IN
        (SELECT DECODE(T1.NRSEQTABLE1,NULL, T2.NRSEQTABLE1, T1.NRSEQTABLE1) AS NRSEQTABLE1
        FROM
          (SELECT NRSEQTABLE1,
            NRNUM2
          FROM TABLE1 T1
          WHERE TO_CHAR(DTHRTABLE1, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
              AND IDRULE                      = 'NO'
          ) T1
        FULL JOIN
          (SELECT NRSEQTABLE1,
            NRNUM2
          FROM TABLE2 T2
          WHERE TO_CHAR(DTHRTABLE2, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
          AND IDRULE                       = 'NO'
          ) T2
        ON T2.NRSEQTABLE1 = T1.NRSEQTABLE1
        AND T2.NRNUM2       = T1.NRNUM2
        )
      GROUP BY TABLE1.NRGROUPBY
      HAVING COUNT(TABLE1.NRSEQTABLE1) > 10
      )
    ORDER BY NRGROUPBY,
      NRSEQTABLE1;
```

Sorry for the english and thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

**1**   A good way to evaluate if a date is part of current month should avoid calling a function on the column values. You should switch

```
TO_CHAR(DTHRTABLE1, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
```

with

```
DTHRTABLE1 >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM') and DTHRTABLE1 < add_months(trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
```

that allows the optimizer to eventually use indexes and that evaluates the functions only once for each query execution, and not once for each table row.

**2**   there's no need to perform any full join for your purpose. Those

```
where id in (
        select id
        from a
            full join b using (id...)
    )
```

are worste way to do

```
where id in (
        select id 
        from a
    )
    or id in (
        select id 
        from b
    )
```

**3**   The second subquery is exsactily the same as the first part of the query so you could use subquery factoring to not evaluate it twice. So you can switch

```
select id1, id2, xyx
from a
where (
        id1 in (
            select id1
            from a
        )
        or id1 in (
            select id1
            from b
        )
    )
    and id2 in (
        select id2
        from a
        where (
                id1 in (
                    select id1
                    from a
                )
                or id1 in (
                    select id1
                    from b
                )
            )
        group by id2
        having xyz2
    )
```

to

```
with src as (
        select id1, id2, xyx
        from a
        where (
                id1 in (
                    select id1
                    from a
                )
                or id1 in (
                    select id1
                    from b
                )
            )
    )
select *
from src
where id2 in (
        select id2
        from src
        group by id2
        having xyz
    )
```

**5** But once the self group by join become so explicit you can switch that pattern to the analytic equivalent witch is faster than it

```
select id1, id2, xyx
from (
        select id1, id2, xyx,
            COUNT(NRSEQTABLE1) over (partition by NRGROUPBY) as cnt
        from a
        where (
                id1 in (
                    select id1
                    from a
                )
                or id1 in (
                    select id1
                    from b
                )
            )
    )
where cnt > 10
```

If you would supply details about uniqueness of the involved columns(especially NRSEQTABLE1, NRNUM2 and NRGROUPBY) I could suggest you some probably better way to improve the performance but, at the moment you can try this query:

```
select *
from (
        SELECT t.*,
            COUNT(NRSEQTABLE1) over (partition by NRGROUPBY) as cnt
        FROM TABLE1 t
        WHERE NRSEQTABLE1 IN (
                SELECT NRSEQTABLE1
                FROM TABLE1 T1
                WHERE DTHRTABLE1 >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM') and DTHRTABLE1 < add_months(trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
                    AND IDRULE = 'NO'
            ) 
            OR NRSEQTABLE1 IN (
                SELECT NRSEQTABLE1
                FROM TABLE2 T2
                WHERE DTHRTABLE2 >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM') and DTHRTABLE2 < add_months(trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
                    AND IDRULE = 'NO'
            )
    )
where cnt > 10
```

**UPDATE**

Given that *"NRSEQTABLE1 is the unique Pk from table1, but in table2 it is the fk"*

the first subquery may be useless because those rows of TABLE1 where

```
NRSEQTABLE1 IN (
        SELECT NRSEQTABLE1
        FROM TABLE1 T1
        WHERE DTHRTABLE1 >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM') and DTHRTABLE1 < add_months(trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
            AND IDRULE = 'NO'
    )
```

are exactly those ones where

```
DTHRTABLE1 >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM') and DTHRTABLE1 < add_months(trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
    AND IDRULE = 'NO'
```

Then your query would be

```
select *
from (
        SELECT t.*,
            COUNT(NRSEQTABLE1) over (partition by NRGROUPBY) as cnt
        FROM TABLE1 t
        WHERE (
                DTHRTABLE1 >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM') and DTHRTABLE1 < add_months(trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
                AND IDRULE = 'NO'
            )
            OR NRSEQTABLE1 IN (
                SELECT NRSEQTABLE1
                FROM TABLE2 T2
                WHERE DTHRTABLE2 >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM') and DTHRTABLE2 < add_months(trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
                    AND IDRULE = 'NO'
            )
    )
where cnt > 10
```

Reading more carefully your question where I noticed that you said *"The idrule must not be no in both tables"*, but this query (so consequentially also the original one) isn't right for this purpose because it checks if "*idrule equals 'NO' at least once in any of the tables TABLE1 and TABLE2*".

Comment: Using union in place of it is not always better, but it may also be. It mostly depends by the cardinality of data, the selectivity of the involved columns and the presence of useful indexes on them. I also think that the first subquery is useless if if NRSEQTABLE1 is unique, but details about this are missing.

Comment: I just realized that if the OP is looking for "COUNT(NRSEQTABLE1)>10", that column is not unique and that it occurs many times. So the first subquery is not useless and using UNION may be better if there are no indexes on NRSEQTABLE1 column for both the tables.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've complete forgot to describe the informations about the columns but without that you gave a very good help. I think I've never seen this partition and with commands, but know that you've explained me I will try to learn about them. But only one question, this commands are exclusive from oracle or they can be used in any database?Here is the info:
NRSEQTABLE1 is the unique Pk from table1, but in table2 it is the fk, therefore it occurs many times in table2, that is why i've used the full join.
Nrgroupby is an fk from other table, on table1, that is not important here...

Comment: And it also occurs many times.
Nrnum2 is a fk from other table also, and it also repeats its value many times throug not only table1, but table2. 
They are all number values.
Anyways, thanks for the help.
Sorry, not just for the stupid question, i'm very new with sql(just my second year learning it, still going to college(i know that doesn't mean nothing in terms of learning sql)), but also because i haven't describe the columns.
(sorry for the english again)

Comment: Analytic functions are surely also available on PostgreSQL and should also be implemented by many other RDBMS. I updated my answer after the PK specification. But I found an ambiguity between your initial requirement and the working query (about IDRULE). I said about it in the last statement of the answer. Try to correct the wrong part in your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WITH` clause also know at CTE. It would be this one:

```
with t1 as 
     (SELECT NRSEQTABLE1, NRNUM2
     FROM TABLE1 T1
     WHERE TO_CHAR(DTHRTABLE1, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
     AND IDRULE = 'NO'),
t2 as 
   (SELECT NRSEQTABLE1, NRNUM2
        FROM TABLE2 T2
        WHERE TO_CHAR(DTHRTABLE2, 'MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/YYYY')
        AND IDRULE = 'NO'),
t3 as 
    (select DECODE(T1.NRSEQTABLE1,NULL, T2.NRSEQTABLE1, T1.NRSEQTABLE1) AS NRSEQTABLE1
    from T1 FULL JOIN T2
      ON T2.NRSEQTABLE1 = T1.NRSEQTABLE1
      AND T2.NRNUM2       = T1.NRNUM2),
t4 as   
    (SELECT NRGROUPBY
      FROM TABLE1
      WHERE NRSEQTABLE1 IN
        (select NRSEQTABLE1 from t3) 
      GROUP BY TABLE1.NRGROUPBY
      HAVING COUNT(TABLE1.NRSEQTABLE1) > 10)
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE NRSEQTABLE1 IN (select NRSEQTABLE1 from t3)            
    AND NRGROUPBY IN (select NRGROUPBY from t4)      
ORDER BY NRGROUPBY, NRSEQTABLE1;
```

Usually it is easier to read and many times it improves performance, because Oracle may create a temporary table on-the-fly to store some data.

Note, query above could contain errors, I just did it on the quick way without any testing. However, you should get an idea how it looks like.